# How to automatically update a column cell based upon other column cells?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Let's say we have three column First Name, Last Name and Full Name.
I want to concatenate first First Name and Last Name columns and show the result in Full Name column.

I tried applying a formula to first column and it's getting concatenated in the first row, but it's not getting updated automatically once I enter the values in a new row.

I want the Full Name column to get updated automatically as soon as I enter values in the first two columns.

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: Which are you using? Excel or Googlesheets? They are not the same...

Comment: Just drag your formula down, or add if both <>"" so no cells with spaces only, or =TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A2:B2) and drag it down, or =BYROW(A2:B100,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,x)))

Comment: You can use tables .. Select the data and press CTRL+T. Your formulas update automatically with tables

Answer (score 0):

Use this `ARRAYFORMULA`:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A & " " & B2:B)

[image: Screenshot]